# What are the xtal pins for esp 12E

Tags: oscillator, clock, esp8266, esp32, crystal

What are the xtal pins on esp 12E? I couldn't find where to hook up the crystal in the datasheet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ESP-12E is a module, not a chip.

It has a crystal onboard the module, and does not provide crystal connections outside the module.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Goto [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1179099/ETC2/ESP12E.html). Figure 4 shows the circuit diagram.

Comment: Yes, it shows the schematics of the module, which shows the module already has a crystal so the module does not need any external crystal.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.